# Miktex Windows API error 32

Tags: packages, miktex, glossaries

I am trying to install the glossaries package but it keeps failing with error 32 (file in use).  There is no other process using the file, unless miktex itself uses separate processes to download and extract it and isn't unlocking the file after download, as there is nothing else running.

I'm using Miktex 2.9.5721x64 on Windows 10, any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Close the editor you're using, or kill all processes involving MiKTeX, then launch MiKTeX Package Manager.

Comment: I have tried this however when I install through the package manager it seems to have installed properly (shows the installed on date and grays out the install option).  I then close the package manager and re-open the tex file, hit compile and it fails saying it could not install the package.  The above error is in the pdflatex log.

Comment: The most common reason, in my experience, is there was an installation while the compiler . was waiting for an order. I would uninstall and re-install properly (i. e. no compiler at work).

Comment: I was under the impression that the compilers are included in miktex, how does one have them running while miktex is installing?

Comment: I suspect you ahead already tried the old "have you tried turning it off and on again" trick? Could it be that anything else TeX-related is running?

Comment: What do you get when you run on a command line `kpsewhich glossaries.sty`?

Comment: @LEGEND383: You misunderstood me. I only meant that, when you install some package after the compiler has stopped, waiting for an answer, you have this type of error, so you must ensure no MiKTeX binary is running before installing whatever.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look into the directory `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` you can the that MiKTeX has several `.dll` files and 119 `.exe` files.

If you try to change one file that is already used by MiKTeX (say: one of the 119 exe files) you get the error 32 (file in use).

To be sure that there is no more MiKTeX process running check with the system panel the running processes or---perhaps easier---reboot the computer (then all running processed had been closed!).

Then you can (re-)install MiKTeX. Use only the install program of MiKTeX to do the install and after the installing run has finished call package manager to bring your installed packages up to date (please understand: installer and package manager are two different programs; the installer has a build-in list of used packages that can differ from the current one! The package manager checks for the installed and current packages and show the difference as "installable packages".)

And please check if the MikTeX homepage contains a new installer program. If yes, download it and use it instead of your old one.